# Generate key value pairs from spark dataframe or RDD with column name present in key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, decision-tree

I have a spark dataframe for which I need key value pairs as shown below. I specifically need the column name in the key. I want to do this using single  mapper pass.

Original Dataset:

[image]

Expected key value pair:(Attribute_Name,Attribute_Value,Class),1

Expected result after single pass of mapper:

Expected Dataset

[image]

Comment: Worst formatting, pls put your example inline.

Comment: Can there be A4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{explode, udf, typedLit}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object test extends App {


  val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local[*]")

  val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("test")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

  val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", true).load("file:///Users/test/Desktop/file2.csv")

  val header: Seq[String] = df.columns.toSeq.map(x => x.trim)

  val df1 = df.withColumn("header", typedLit(header))

  val transform = udf((col0: String, col1: String, col2: String, col3: String, header: Seq[String]) => {
    Array(
      ((header(0), col0.trim, col3.trim),1),
      ((header(1), col1.trim, col3.trim),1),
      ((header(2), col2.trim, col3.trim),1)
    )
  })

  val df2 = df1.withColumn("transformed",transform($"A1", $" A2", $" A3", $" Class", $"header"))
    .withColumn("exploded", explode($"transformed"))
    .select($"exploded")

  df2.take(1).foreach(println)
}
```

Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmCUM.jpg

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. That works fine if i have less than 22 columns like A1, A2...A22. But if I have more than that, it throws error saying that maximum allowed parameters is 22 for the UDF method. I tried passing values through array but it does not work. Any way around this?